# How to display two d3 wordclouds on one page

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js, word-cloud

I'm trying to put two (or even more -> that depends on the users settings) d3 Wordclouds to one page. However I'll get the following result:

[image]

It seems, that the word list won't be parsed correct.

My code looks like this:
(The php $Block variable specifies the position, where the recent wordcloud should be shown.)

```
var container = "svg_<?php echo $Block;?>";

var w = $('#word_cloud_<?php echo $Block;?>').width();
var h = w*0.75;

if($( window ).width()<400){
    var maxRange=20;
}else if($( window ).width()<800){
    var maxRange=40;
}else if($( window ).width()<1200){
    var maxRange=60;
}else if($( window ).width()>=1200){
    var maxRange=95;
}

var list_<?php echo $Block;?>=<?php echo $jsonWort; ?>;

var wordSize=12;
var layout;

generate_<?php echo $Block;?>(list_<?php echo $Block;?>);

function generate_<?php echo $Block;?>(list) {

    //Blacklist wird gefiltert!
    var blacklist=["ein","sind"];
    list=list.filter(function(x) { return blacklist.indexOf(x) < 0 });

    // Liste wird verarbeitet
    result = { };
    for(i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
        if(!result[list[i]])
            result[list[i]] = 0;
        ++result[list[i]];
    }

    var newList = _.uniq(list);



    var frequency_list = [];
    var len = newList.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        var temp = newList[i];
        frequency_list.push({
            text : temp,
            freq : result[newList[i]],
            time : 0 
        });

    }
    frequency_list.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(b.freq) - parseFloat(a.freq) } );  


    for(var t = 0 ; t < len ; t++)
    {
        var addTime = (100 * t) +500;
        frequency_list[t].time=addTime;
    }


    for(i in frequency_list){
        if(frequency_list[i].freq*wordSize > 160)   
            wordSize = 3;
    }


    var sizeScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(frequency_list,  function(d) { return d.freq} )]).range([5, maxRange]);
    layout= d3.layout.cloud().size([w, h])
        .words(frequency_list)
        .padding(5)
        .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
        .font("Impact")
        .fontSize(function(d) { return sizeScale(d.freq); })
        .on("end",draw)
        .start();
}


function draw(words) {

    var fill = d3.scale.category20();

    d3.select(container).remove();

    d3.select("#word_cloud_<?php echo $Block;?>").append(container)
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h) 
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + [w/2, h/2] + ")")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
        .enter().append("text")

        .transition()
        .duration(function(d) { return d.time}  )
        .attr('opacity', 1)
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .style("font-family", "Impact")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
    })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
    })
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
}
```

I believe that the mistake has to be somewhere in

```
   var sizeScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(frequency_list,  function(d) { return d.freq} )]).range([5, maxRange]);
layout= d3.layout.cloud().size([w, h])
    .words(frequency_list)
    .padding(5)
    .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
    .font("Impact")
    .fontSize(function(d) { return sizeScale(d.freq); })
    .on("end",draw)
    .start();
```

But I'm not able to find it.

Comment: Ok, it seems that the problem is `var container = "svg_<?php echo $Block;?>";` when I write `var container = "svg";` everything works quite well. But if there are two or more wordclouds, the container will be overwritten and finally there will be shown only one wordcloud (the last one). How can a workaround look like?

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite it because of the line

```
d3.select(container).remove();
```

With d3 you are basically creating complex SVGs on the fly. You can have as many elements as you want. As long as you do not remove them, they'll remain there. But you need to also make sure that they do not overlap. See [here](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-group-element-and-d3js) and (very cool!) [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1345853)